# How set first row in phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, drupal, phpexcel

How to set the first row in phpexcel, i really new for this stuff when i export file using phpexcel the result always start with A1 row ! how to skip it..?
i want to start insert my data in other row like A4 or any else.
this is what i have in my code (update full code)

```
 function theme_views_data_export_xlsx_body(&$vars) {
 _views_data_export_header_shared_preprocess($vars);
 _views_data_export_body_shared_preprocess($vars);
 $complete_array = array_merge(array($vars['header']), $vars['themed_rows']);
  // Decode HTML entities.
  foreach ($complete_array as &$row) {
  foreach ($row as &$value) {
  $value = decode_entities($value);
  }
}

 // Load PHPExcel library.
 $library = libraries_load('PHPExcel');

 // Create PHPExcel spreadsheet and add rows to it.


  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F1', '=E2');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($complete_array);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Nilai Ukk');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);
  // $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->getAlignment()-
 >setWrapText(true);
   $excel_type = 'excel2007';
   switch ($excel_type) {
   default:
   case 'excel2007':
  $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
  break;
 }

 // Catch the output of the spreadsheet.
  ob_start();

  $objWriter->save('php://output');
  $excelOutput = ob_get_clean();
   return $excelOutput;
   }
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `->setCellValue('A4', 'Your Data')`, etc?

Comment: yes but no luck..!

Answer (score 0):

According to Mark Baker you can do the following to skip first header row:

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$sheetData = $sheet->rangeToArray(
    'A2:' . $highestColumn . $highestRow,
    NULL,TRUE,FALSE
);
```

See this: [PHPExcel toArray skip first header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456375/phpexcel-toarray-skip-first-header-row)

Comment: Thanks, but i guess it not what i want just check my full code above i really appreciate for helping me..:)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skip row 1. don't set entire row field as `NULL`

You need to define a variable

```
$row = 2; // skip first row set direct value 2
```

Now you can use that variable in 
`setCellValue("A{$row}", 'Your_Value');`
it will set `Your_Value` in `A2` field of excel sheet.

You can increment variable `$row++` to add additional data to next row.

Comment: I have update my fullcode maybe you can help whre i have to that code to set my first row..thanks

Comment: Write this line as:- `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('F{$row}', '=E2');`

Comment: i got this error..'PHPExcel_Exception: Cell coordinate must not be absolute. in PHPExcel_Worksheet->getCell()' when i use your code